# how to launch sonarqube?

Tags: elasticsearch, java-8, sonarqube

for my studies I need to install sonarqube on an ubuntu server.

I installed it following this tutorial : http://www.naturalborncoder.com/methodology/2015/05/27/sonarqube-on-ubuntu-14-04/ (I stopped before the proxying part) but I can't access to 127.0.0.1:9000. From the logs it look like there is a problem with elasticsearch when i launch sonarcube.

/opt/sonar/log/sonar.log :

```html
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2017.11.14 18:21:11 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonar/temp
2017.11.14 18:21:11 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2017.11.14 18:21:11 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonar/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonar/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Epath.conf=/opt/sonar/temp/conf/es
2017.11.14 18:21:11 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2017.11.14 18:21:13 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2017.11.14 18:21:13 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
java.security.policy: error adding Entry:
        java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ${codebase.elasticsearch-rest-client}
java.security.policy: error adding Entry:
        java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ${codebase.httpasyncclient-4.1.2.jar}
java.security.policy: error adding Entry:
        java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ${codebase.netty-common-4.1.13.Final.jar}
java.security.policy: error adding Entry:
        java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ${codebase.netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar}
java.security.policy: error adding Entry:
        java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ${codebase.securesm-1.1.jar}
java.security.policy: error adding Entry:
        java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ${codebase.lucene-core-6.6.1.jar}
java.security.policy: error adding Entry:
        java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ${codebase.lucene-misc-6.6.1.jar}
2017.11.14 18:21:27 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
2017.11.14 18:21:27 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
2017.11.14 18:21:27 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

/opt/sonar/logs/es.log :

```html
2017.11.14 18:21:24 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] initializing ...
2017.11.14 18:21:24 INFO  es[][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/vda1)]], net usable_space [5.7gb], net total_space [9.6gb], spins? [possibly], types [ext4]
2017.11.14 18:21:24 INFO  es[][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment] heap size [503.6mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
2017.11.14 18:21:24 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] node name [sonarqube], node ID [3PxDbRbDQ4-M_YDsv25FHg]
2017.11.14 18:21:24 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] version[5.6.3], pid[8661], build[1a2f265/2017-10-06T20:33:39.012Z], OS[Linux/4.4.0-22-generic/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/9-internal/9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.b$
2017.11.14 18:21:24 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] JVM arguments [-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, $
2017.11.14 18:21:26 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
2017.11.14 18:21:26 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [ingest-common]
2017.11.14 18:21:26 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [parent-join]
2017.11.14 18:21:26 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [percolator]
2017.11.14 18:21:26 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [reindex]
2017.11.14 18:21:26 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [transport-netty4]
2017.11.14 18:21:26 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no plugins loaded
2017.11.14 18:21:27 ERROR es[][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] fatal error in thread [main], exiting
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.miscellaneous.StemmerOverrideFilter$Builder.build(StemmerOverrideFilter.java:205) ~[lucene-analyzers-common-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1 9aa465a89b64ff2dabe7b4d50c472de32c298683 - varunthacker - 2017-08-29 21:55$
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.nl.DutchAnalyzer.<init>(DutchAnalyzer.java:133) ~[lucene-analyzers-common-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1 9aa465a89b64ff2dabe7b4d50c472de32c298683 - varunthacker - 2017-08-29 21:55:17]
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.nl.DutchAnalyzer.<init>(DutchAnalyzer.java:106) ~[lucene-analyzers-common-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1 9aa465a89b64ff2dabe7b4d50c472de32c298683 - varunthacker - 2017-08-29 21:55:17]
        at org.elasticsearch.indices.analysis.PreBuiltAnalyzers$20.create(PreBuiltAnalyzers.java:246) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.indices.analysis.PreBuiltAnalyzers.getAnalyzer(PreBuiltAnalyzers.java:487) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.AnalysisRegistry$PrebuiltAnalysis.<init>(AnalysisRegistry.java:407) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.AnalysisRegistry$PrebuiltAnalysis.<init>(AnalysisRegistry.java:392) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.AnalysisRegistry.<init>(AnalysisRegistry.java:62) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.indices.analysis.AnalysisModule.<init>(AnalysisModule.java:177) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:340) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:245) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:233) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:233) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:342) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:132) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:123) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:70) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:134) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:91) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:84) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers")
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:468) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:894) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:541) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Class.checkMemberAccess(Class.java:2584) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:2092) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.lucene.util.RamUsageEstimator$1.run(RamUsageEstimator.java:339) ~[lucene-core-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1 9aa465a89b64ff2dabe7b4d50c472de32c298683 - varunthacker - 2017-08-29 21:54:39]
        at org.apache.lucene.util.RamUsageEstimator$1.run(RamUsageEstimator.java:336) ~[lucene-core-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1 9aa465a89b64ff2dabe7b4d50c472de32c298683 - varunthacker - 2017-08-29 21:54:39]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.lucene.util.RamUsageEstimator.shallowSizeOfInstance(RamUsageEstimator.java:336) ~[lucene-core-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1 9aa465a89b64ff2dabe7b4d50c472de32c298683 - varunthacker - 2017-08-29 21:54:39]
        at org.apache.lucene.util.RamUsageEstimator.shallowSizeOf(RamUsageEstimator.java:313) ~[lucene-core-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1 9aa465a89b64ff2dabe7b4d50c472de32c298683 - varunthacker - 2017-08-29 21:54:39]
        at org.apache.lucene.util.fst.ByteSequenceOutputs.<clinit>(ByteSequenceOutputs.java:154) ~[lucene-core-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1 9aa465a89b64ff2dabe7b4d50c472de32c298683 - varunthacker - 2017-08-29 21:54:39]
        ... 21 more
```

java -version :

```
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

sonarqube version : 6.7

I launch sonarqube as root so there should not have problem coming from access right.

All the post that i find about this error where related with openjdk9 but this is not my case.

Do you have an idea of what is happening ?

Comment: Check the access rights on all relevant SonarQube folders for the user starting SonarQube?

Comment: I started sonarqube as root so i guess that there should be no access rights problem

Comment: You should never use Elasticsearch as root. Also mention the SonarQube version you use.

Comment: I use the version 6.7. if I try to launch it as a normal user it ask me to "authenticate" with a password but I don't have one (only a ssh key)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://michalwegrzyn.wordpress.com/2016/07/14/do-not-run-sonar-as-root/) helps?

Comment: thanks but I think that it is for an old version of sonarqube : I have nothing such as /opt/sonar/bin/sonar.sh
Anyway using root to launch it is a security concern but it shouldn't (?) cause the crash of elasticsearch.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

SonarQube 6.7 includes an upgraded version of Elasticsearch which *cannot* be run as root. Thus, SonarQube can no longer be run as root.

The blog post you followed seems to recommend / assume that you're running as root. To not start SonarQube as root, simply end your `su` session, or log back in as yourself to start the process. Note that you'll need to make sure the user you *are* starting SonarQube as has 7 (read, write, execute) on the SonarQube directory, recursively, and 6 (read, write) on the log files if they already exist.

Comment: thanks for the information. how could I run it without root ? I've tried to add `RUN_AS_USER=sonar` in /opt/sonar/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh but it still ask me to authenticate :
`==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to start 'sonar.service'.
Authenticating as: Ubuntu (ubuntu)
Password: `


the ubuntu user is the user with root access.

Comment: if someone pass here trying to launch it as a non-root user you will have to launch it as a service; it look like it is not possible otherwise (?)

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the Java version was the problem.

I installed Oracle JDK 8 for for sonarcube 6.7.1, which resolved the problem:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java    
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

You can read more about the supported platforms [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements). For now, only Java 8 is supported.

Comment: This also fixed it for me. The system had ended up with OpenJDK 9 set as the default JRE, which SonarQube doesn't support yet.

Comment: I had the same issue with sonarqube-8.7.1.42226 with jdk 16. when i changed my java version to 11 , the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I got the following error in cmd:

> INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up
>   and running INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded INFO 
>   app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin
>   [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin] WARN 
>   app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value
>   [es]: 1 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped INFO 
>   app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped

It had problems setting up Elasticsearch on its default port number 9001. (You can check it in the logs folder: `.\sonarqube-7.6\logs`)

I just changed the port number from 9001 to 0 in the sonarqube properties file.
Go to- `.\sonarqube-7.6\conf\sonar.properties` and set `sonar.search.port=0`
Port 0 takes any port which is unused.

Good luck with the changes